# How to convert specific htaccess to global httpd.conf

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

How can I convert

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

in the global httpd.conf configuration. One immediate problem is that there is no RewriteBase rule allowed in httpd.conf. But to know how to rewrite this, it might help to understand what these rules do.

What does RewriteBase / do? Does it mean that it will take any incoming URL and delete everything between the server name and last item in the URL and delete it? That is, http://example.com/dir1/dir2/file becomes http://example.com/file?
I think the second rule means that a URL like http://example.com/index.php is left untouched.

The third and fourth lines check to see if filename being requested exists as file or directory and if they do, then the following rewrite rule is ignored.

In the last line, the rewrite rule is confusing, it seems to want to match on any single character and just a single character (why is it not ^(.*)$) and if that somehow matches, then rewrite the whole line as /index.php which then seems to somehow know how to process the URL of http://example.com/index.php as it still contains what was originally submitted.

Comment: There is a very good official documentation which explains in detail what those directives do: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: It's actually quite useless for answering my specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

**RewriteBase**: you can have RewriteBase in httpd.conf.  Just under a `<Directory>` block.  Look at the documentation, there is an example.

Here this was inside a .htaccess file somewhere in the directory structure.  It is forcing the rewrite engine to start from `/` and not from the directory where the .htaccess file is found.

---

**Second line**: you are correct, if it is not an existing file.

---

**Third and fourth line**: you are correct, if it is not an existing directory.

---

**Last line**: if the request is not an existing file, and is not an existing directory, and is 1 character long ==> whatever the character is (matched by the .), return index.php.

I agree with you, it should be `^(.*)$` to match anything that is not an existing directory of file.  Just a single dot is quite restrictive, although there might be a logic behind it on your particular site.

---

Details for the `.`

- `.`: matches any character
- `.+`: matches 1 or more .  So any number of characters, NOT including 0 chars.
- `.*`: matches 0 or more .  So any number of characters, including 0 chars.

Comment: Presumably, the goal is to take virtual URLs, rewrite them to index.php and the code internally takes the virtual URL in a global variable and processes it.

The .htaccess file is in the root, so it's not clear why there needs to be a RewriteBase at all then. Would it not be doing anything at all, then?

If the line RewriteRule . /index.php just matches on just a lone character, it's not clear when it would match on anything, but clearly that's not what's happening. It's matching on almost everything. It does not match on https://neuronair.org/wp-login.php and it's not clear why.

Comment: I see why it doesn't match wp-login.php. It's a real file.